# MVC2 in jsp/servlet application

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here's the scenario, I am working on a web-based application develped used JSP/Servlet technique, and we adopt MVC2 as an architectural design pattern, we put all the methods that make manipulation on database into one class, for example, addNewUser() , updateUserInfo (),
all methods that make connection to db and manipulate data are in one class.

what is the role of this class, controller or model?

Comment: the question is unclear. And the tags make it more unclear.

Comment: @Bozho, I update my post,please have a look over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the (business) model.

The controller should be the servlet and the view should be the JSP.